# Get specific values from text boxes into Grid View?

Tags: c#, sql, database, t-sql, c#-4.0

I am new in Databases so please ignore my way asking !

I have two text boxes named from date and To date having calendar within them  and now i want to get data from them in grid view against specific dates selected in those text boxes.

I have Created Stored Procedure for this operation but i am not sure much about my stored procedure.

here is my stored procedure

```
select * from cor_leave 
where dt_from >= @dt_from and dt_from <= @dt_to
```

i am going on right way or if i am doing any wrong please help me out?
or is there any way that can solve my issue???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are going right. But, note that the `dt_from` has to be of data type compatible with the data type `date` in order to get you the correct date range that you are looking for.

You can also use `BETWEEN` instead of `>=` and `<=`:

```
SELECT *
FROM cor_leave 
WHERE dt_from BETWEEN @dt_from AND @dt_to
```

Answer (score 0):

You should query in this way:

```
select * from cor_leave 
where dt_from between @dt_from and @dt_to
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, it may happen that your `dt_to` remains `NULL`.

In that case your query will not bring records with `@dt_to` as null.

To avoid such issue refer below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cor_leave  
WHERE dt_from BETWEEN @dt_from AND ISNULL(@dt_to,dt_from)
```